# Using another server as a gateway

Tags: networking, vpn, gateway

I have a server set up off site and I want to VPN it to another site. Problem is we can only have 2 VPN connections at once.

Is there a way to configure one server to be connected by VPN and tell all the other servers off site to use that server as the default gateway so all servers can see the machines on the other side of the VPN?

```
Server B1 --->                GATEWAY
Server B2 ---> Server B4 connected by VPN to ServerA1 ---> VPN Server (ServerA1) ---> On Site Network
Server B3 --->
```

Comment: You already have your answer: You have to set server B4 as the other machines’ default gateway. You may have to enable routing on B4.

Comment: Just thought about it and realised I was properly stupid! Thanks for reminding me...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set other machine's default gateway to that server and enable Routing in Remote Access and Routing.